# 500, InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm having an issue where I'm getting an internal server error when returning CreatedAtRoute. I confirmed it's the source of the issue, I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
[HttpGet("{steamId64}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBan([FromQuery] string apiKey, [FromRoute] long steamId64)
{
    // Code omitted
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostBan([FromQuery] string apiKey, [FromBody] Ban ban)
{
    // Code omitted

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetBan", new { apiKey, steamId64 = ban.SteamId64 }, ban); // 500
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding `Name` value to your get method like this

```
[HttpGet("{steamId64}", Name = "GetBan")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetBan([FromQuery] string apiKey, 
[FromRoute] long steamId64)
{
    // Code omitted
}
```

Comment: I assumed it used reflection. Thank you very much.